# Custom Map iPhone

Tags: iphone

I trying to figure out how to create a Custom Map like the following:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mall-book-california/id342584415?mt=8

http://www.macworld.com/appguide/app.html?id=541350&expand=false

I just don't know where to start from, do I use UIWebView or MapKit? 
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we did in our app is use a `UIImageView` on a `UIScrollView`. You need to take a screenshot of the object you will map on the google-map and precisely draw your overlay over it. Also you need to take the top left coordinate and bottom right coordinate of the screenshot you took from the map. Then put the overlay image inside an imageview, image view on scrollview, and scale your coordinate system on the scrollview with the coordinates you took from the map. Now you can precisely plot POI-s on your overlay. A note: The first thing we did is we overlaid the g-map with custom image view but it was really slow when scrolled, so don't even try it. Good luck with coding.

[EDIT] you take a large screenshot of an area on google map like this
http://www.metacafe.com/watch/1073912/google_maps_hack_how_to_save_large_maps/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What do you mean by take a screenshot of the map? Since it going to be a custom map not related to google maps. Do I than need to have coordinates of it?

Comment: If you have a need for placing POIs on your custom map which are on real GPS coordinates, then you need to know what the coordinates of the upper and lower corner are right? So if you have a custom map of a castle you need to match it with its actual geolocation, which you can attain by taking a large screenshot of it from google maps. Then you just need to match the overlay with the actual satellite image. If you dont need to place pois on actual GPS coordinates then you don't need to do this. Just place UIButtons for POIs on the scrollview where you need to.

Comment: Hi can u tell me in details how to achieve this . If possible can u share some code.

Comment: Hi Vijay, unfortunately I cannot share the code since it's protected under copyright. Read carefully and I think you'll get it, it's not that difficult really.